# How to prove that, $T\left(\int_a^b f(t)dt\right) =\int_a^b T\circ f(t)dt $

Tags: integration, analysis, banach-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $T:E\to F$ be a linear and continuous function between the Banach spaces $E$ and $F$.

We consider $f:\to [a,b]\to E$ (with $a<b $) be an integrable  function in [the sense of Bochner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral)

How do I prove that $$T\left(\int_a^b f(t)dt\right) =\int_a^b T\circ f(t)dt $$
I don't know from which  argument $T$ cross the integral. Please Help.

Comment: Whenever in doubt, prove the result for step functions, then simple functions and finally the whole space. Bochner integrals are defined through limits of simple functions so this should be straight-forward

Comment: The things you need: $T$ is linear; $T$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove that in exactly the same way  you would do it in conventional measure theory. First you can prove it with

$$\phi=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n b_i 1_{E_i}$$

A simple function, then

$$\int T \phi=\int \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n  Tb_i1_{E_i}=\int \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n b_i 1_{TE_i}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \mu(TE_i)=T\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \mu(E_i)=T\int \phi$$

And so $f_n\uparrow f$ then

$$\int Tf=\lim \int Tf_n=T \lim \int f_n=T\int f$$